# Example form on posting data through JInput class

Tags: jdatabase, jinput

I've been told numerous times to use JInput Class as opposed to using 'method="post" on my forms.  I have no problem finding example of how to retrieve data using JInput, but after searching numerous times over the past year, I can not find a single example of this from start to finish (HTML form to database to data retrieval from the database).  Luckily, everything I've been building has not been public (it's been secure via Joomla... only available to administrators).  But I would like to start using it just as a best practice.  A single link to an example would be much appreciated.  Or a download of the entire procedure via a GitHub project would work.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of that.  Probably the best place to look, Tom.  If you want to put this in the 'answers' as opposed to 'comments', I'll mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JInput should replace the old JRequest only. It is used to retrieving any request data. I cannot agree with "using JInput class as opposed to 'method="post"' in forms. You'll find best practice in the sources of joomla core.